# 2023 From Numbers 1-15

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Using the numbers 1, 2, 3,..., 15, in that order, how can you make the number 2023 using the +, -, $\times$, and $\div$ operations. (You can use as many parentheses as you want.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without parentheses:

> $1+2*3+4+5+6-7-8+9*10+11*12*13+14*15=2023$